# Error in starting hadoop Job Tracker

Tags: hadoop

I tried to run a simple program in hadoop using Windows-Cygwin.

I am able to start the namenode .

The jobtracker start however fails with exception :

```
FATAL mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4978)
```

I tried all possible methods to resolve this ,but in vain. Any pointers will greatly help me.

**Hdfs-site.xml  configurations :**

```
 <configuration><br>
   <property>
     <name>fs.default.name< /name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9100</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>mapred.job.tracker< /name>
     <value>localhost:9101< /value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.replication< /name>
     <value>1</value>
   </property> 
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is the following lines should on into **mapred-site.xml** and NOT hdfs-site.xml,

```
<property> 
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
<value>localhost:9101</value> 
</property>
```

By the way why are you trying to run Hadoop in Windows? For development? You don't have a linux machine or reluctant to install one?

One more thing, you usually put this property in core-site.xml not hdfs-site.xml,

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9100</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Why is it unreasonable to want to run Hadoop on Windows, other than in doing so one runs against the Hadoop community's continual blinkered view of the world that suggests there is only one acceptable operating system?

Comment: Normally Hadoop people think Windows machine as a child's video game. Not any serious thing. I think when they get tired of work, they use windows machine's wall paper things.

Comment: Because while it may be possible to run Hadoop on Windows, the code was developed entirely in the Linux environment and as such running it on Windows will introduce variables that are not expected and lead to further complications of something that is already very complicated.  Hadoop does a lot of file operations, and while Java may run on Windows, not all native operations work quite the same, especially filesystem operations.  That it runs on windows at all is something of a Miracle.  The question isnt why would you want to run it on Windows, it is why would you want the misery of unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when working on the "Pseudo Distributed" examples as at this page: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/single_node_setup.html#PseudoDistributed

It turned out that hadoop simply wasn't picking up my conf files. The examples at the link above assume you are running in your install of hadoop (i.e. /Usr/jane/hadoop-1.1.2). I was trying to run the examples in another directory. I'm sure you could configure hadoop to recognize other 'conf' directories, but I took the easy route and just started running in my hadoop directory.

This thread helped me figure it out: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2515

Comment: Btw, I found this page a helpful corollary to the hadoop setup page: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/hadoop-modes-explained-standalone.html
This page shows pretty much the same examples but with additional info on expected output.