# hadoop job tracker cannot start up

Tags: hadoop, jobs, tracker

Under the Single Node Setup
I try to run a single node example
The jobtracker start however fails with exception :

```
2013-04-30 17:12:54,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-04-30 17:12:54,994 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-04-30 17:12:54,995 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-04-30 17:12:54,995 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started
2013-04-30 17:12:55,078 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source QueueMetrics,q=default registered.
2013-04-30 17:12:55,104 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4978)

2013-04-30 17:12:55,105 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down JobTracker at calmatery-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker></name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in your `mapred-site.xml`. You specified:

```
<name>mapred.job.tracker></name>
                        ^
```

but

```
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
```

would be correct. Notice the erroneous `>` character before `</name>` in your config file.

If this does not help, try https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2515  and [Error in starting hadoop Job Tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059604/error-in-starting-hadoop-job-tracker).