# Unable to start jobtracker and tasktracker

Tags: java, hadoop

I am able to start the namenode and secondary namenode but I am not able to start jobtracker and tasktracker.

When I check log it shows something like this

```
************************************************************/
2013-05-30 07:27:50,962 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: top-level element not <configuration>
2013-05-30 07:27:50,963 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:50,963 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:50,963 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-05-30 07:27:51,360 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-05-30 07:27:51,365 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-05-30 07:27:51,365 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
2013-05-30 07:27:51,440 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2013-05-30 07:27:51,587 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: top-level element not <configuration>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,587 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,588 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,588 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,594 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-05-30 07:27:51,603 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-05-30 07:27:51,773 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: top-level element not <configuration>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,773 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,773 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,773 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
2013-05-30 07:27:51,799 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3937)

2013-05-30 07:27:51,805 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at ubuntu2/192.168.44.131
************************************************************/
```

Comment: It says "bad conf file" everywhere in the logs, that should give you a hint.

Comment: Share your mapred-site.xml

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with your config files: core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml. As per the error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port
>   authority: local

Do look for correct values and if the xml is valid (a small typo can ruin it).
Try these :  [hadoop job tracker cannot start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296589/hadoop-job-tracker-cannot-start-up) and [Error in starting hadoop Job Tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059604/error-in-starting-hadoop-job-tracker)